# How to loop this test with different csv row?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am beginner with selenium tests. I wrote this code and it works, but I need to loop this test with another csv line.

I spent almost 10 hours trying to do this.

Scenario of what I am trying to do:

1. The web browser is opening  go to url
2. login with data from CSV file from first line
3. Driver is restarting and do the same but with data from second line from csv file.

I also tried to restart test with aftermethod/afterclass but it's not working.

```
public class CSVdataread {
    private WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "URL";
    String CSV_file = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\TestData.csv";

    @BeforeClass
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("URL");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void verify_Search() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(CSV_file));
        String[] cell;

        while((cell = reader.readNext()) != null) 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                String name = cell[i];
                String email = cell[i + 1];
                String baseUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxx/xxxx/";
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='useridFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(name);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userpasswordFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(email);
                {
                    driver.quit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit 4 solution. This one is going to be huge...

First, let's start off with `CSVReader` and some good practices plus code readability. In your test, you read CSV data and use them in your tests. It's not the test's responsibility to read data. The test should already have all the data provided to it. It's called `DataProvider`. This term is actually used in `TestNG` testing framework, just like @user861594 suggested.

So, you should have something to provide data to your tests. But this already Step #2. Since you know you will read data row-by-row from CSV file, you should create a proper class to read the data from CSV.

Here's an example:

```
public class CSVReader {
    private static final String DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ",";
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private List<String> lines;

    public CSVReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        lines = this.reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String[] getRow(int rowNumber) {
        return lines.get(rowNumber).split(DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return lines.size();
    }
}
```

The `CSVReader` constructor accepts a `File` as an argument and creates proper objects to read data in a specific manner (for example: read as `String`). Then, the data in the CSV file is read, just like in normal TXT file by saving the lines in the memory for later use.

Then we create 2 methods. First is `getRowCount` which gives us the total number of row/set of data.

Second is `getRow` which collect the specific row from the list and saves it to `String[]` array for later use.

`String[]` array has a presentation like 1 Excel row:

```
data index 0 | data index 1 | data index 2 | data index 3
```

We have a class which allows us to read the file in an easy matter. Let's create the `DataProvider`

To provide data to tests, we need to use `@Parameters` annotation and return `Collection<Object[]>` to our test. I will talk later about that.

So, let's implement it in our `DataProvider`

```
public class CSVDataProvider {

    public Collection<Object[]> getData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new File("C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\TestData.csv"));
        int rowCount = reader.getRowCount();
        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            Object[] singleRow = reader.getRow(i);
            data[i][0] = singleRow[0];
            data[i][1] = singleRow[1];
        }

        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
}
```

I assume that you have only logins and passwords in the CSV file. That's why I created a 2-dimensional array `new Object[rowCount][2]`. We create the array by providing how many elements it has to store and we know how many rows we have from `rowCount` variable.
2 means we have only 2 data per row. Login and password. If you want to use additional element, for example - the role of the user, you can modify to `[3]`

In the `for` loop we are transforming the data from the CSV file to array and return it for later use.

Now, let's talk about our test class.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class OurTest {
    private String login, password;

    public OurTest(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: Login: ({0}) Password: ({1})")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new CSVDataProvider().getData();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(String.format("login : %s | Password: %s", login, password));
    }
}
```

In order to pass the parameters from `DataProvider` to our test, we need to 
 1. Annotate the class with `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`
 2. Create a method returning `Collection<Object[]> with annotation`@Parameters`
 3. Create a constructor reflecting what kind of data do we accept.

Regarding point 3, that's why I created a 2 argument constructor with `String login` and `String password`. We are passing those 2 parameters. JUnit will create a new instance of `OurTest` and pass different row for each test.

In the `test` method I just printed the data we've got from the `DataProvider`

I do not present a fully working solution because I want you to try to adjust your test to learn this specific approach. It's also called `Data-driven Testing`.

We have only 1 test method but each line in the CSV file will run as a separate test.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop looks broken. The for loop inside the while loop seems to mess up your login procedure.

```
while((cell = reader.readNext())!=null) { // iterate through csv file
  String name = cell[0]; // cell is current row, you need first column for name
  String email = cell[1]; // second column for email (as password?)
  // what do you want to do with baseUrl here?

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='useridFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(name);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userpasswordFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(email);

  // you need to check the successful login here
  // then logout and open main page
  // do not quit before you are finished 
}

// quit after the loop is finished
driver.quit();
```

Without any knowledge of the website it is impossible to tell you how to check successful login and perform logout.

May I suggest you put some effort in learning the ropes with a less complex task? You seem to have a lot of trouble with basic Java elements. Never stop learning.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you want to iterate your test with set of test data. In that case you should use TestNG [data provider](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) feature.

```
public class CSVdataread {
    private WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "URL";
    String CSV_file = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\TestData.csv";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="users-data")
    public void verify_Search(String name, String email) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
           String baseUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxx/xxxx/";
           driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='useridFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(name);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userpasswordFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(email);
     }
     //This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
     @DataProvider(name = "users-data")
     public Iterator<Object[]> createDataFromCSV() {
       CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(CSV_file));
       List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
       //read csv data to list
       return data.iterator();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }

 }
```

You can also utilize available [data-provider-extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension). For example, with qaf You don't need to write code for driver management or for data provider. Your test class will look like below:

```
public class CSVdataread  extends WebDriverTestCase{

    @QAFDataProvider(dataFile="resources/user-data.csv")
    @Test()
    public void verify_Search(String name, String email) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
           String baseUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxx/xxxx/";
           getDriver().navigate().to(baseUrl);
           getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='useridFormField-inputEl']")).sendKeys(name);
           //another way of finding element...
           getDriver().findElement("xpath=//input[@id='userpasswordFormField-inputEl']").sendKeys(email);
     }
 }
```